# UITableview reloadData is not resetting frame for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm adding new cells to a table view using a pull to add function. When you pull down on the table view past a threshold a placeholder cell is added. Then, I call reloadData and becomeFirstResponder on the placeholder cell.

The problem is reloadData doesn't appear to be resetting the tableview frame for iPhone 5 and lower. This causes the placeholder cell to be out of visible range. The table offset should be 0.

**Add Placeholder**

```
-(void)todoPlaceHolderAdded {
    NSLog(@"todoPlaceHolderAdded");

    // create the new item
    TodoItem *newItem = [[TodoItem alloc] initWithText:@""];
    [_todoList insertObject:newItem atIndex:0];

    // refresh the table
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // find new cell
    ToDoCell* editCell;
    for (ToDoCell* cell in _tableView.visibleCells) {
        if (cell.todoItem == newItem) {
            editCell = cell;
            editCell.todoItem = newItem;
            _cellInEdit = cell;
            editCell.textField.placeholder = @"Enter task";
            break;
        }
    }

    // enter edit mode
    [editCell.textField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

**Edit Cell**

```
-(void)cellDidBeginEditing:(ToDoCell *)editingCell {
    NSLog(@"cellDidBeginEditing");
    _tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _tableView.bounces = NO;
    _superViewHorizontalScroll.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _cellInEdit = editingCell;

    //Set offset to current editing cell
    _editingOffset = _tableView.contentOffset.y - editingCell.frame.origin.y;

    NSLog(@"Table Offset: %f", _tableView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog(@"Frame y: %f", editingCell.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"Offset: %f", _editingOffset);

    //Slide rows to editing cell
    for(ToDoCell* cell in [_tableView visibleCells]) {
        //Add flag for cells that edit is in progress
        cell.isEditing = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
            animations:^{
                //Set new frame for cell
                cell.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.frame, 0, _editingOffset);

                //Reduce alpha for non editing cells
                if (cell != _cellInEdit) {
                    cell.alpha = 0.2;
                }
        }];
    }
}
```

**iPhone 5 and Lower**

```
2015-04-25 23:09:39.093 QuickScrollTest[7996:320879] todoPlaceHolderAdded
2015-04-25 23:09:39.093 QuickScrollTest[7996:320879] cellDidBeginEditing
2015-04-25 23:09:39.093 QuickScrollTest[7996:320879] Table Offset: -136.000000
2015-04-25 23:09:39.093 QuickScrollTest[7996:320879] Frame y: 0.000000
2015-04-25 23:09:39.093 QuickScrollTest[7996:320879] Offset: -136.000000
```

**iPhone 6**

```
2015-04-25 23:11:01.071 QuickScrollTest[8179:323067] todoPlaceHolderAdded
2015-04-25 23:11:01.078 QuickScrollTest[8179:323067] cellDidBeginEditing
2015-04-25 23:11:01.078 QuickScrollTest[8179:323067] Table Offset: 0.000000
2015-04-25 23:11:01.078 QuickScrollTest[8179:323067] Frame y: 0.000000
2015-04-25 23:11:01.078 QuickScrollTest[8179:323067] Offset: 0.000000
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial doing exactly what you need: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13